# Python. Импорт py-файла

Tags: python, файлы, input

Есть небольшой код, создающий **py-файл** с переменными.

```
from os import path,chdir

def write_hero_varStat(file_name,file_writeOption,*HERO_STAT):

   chdir("saves/")
   File = open(file_name+".py",file_writeOption)

   var_name = lambda x:[ n for n in globals() if id(globals()[n]) == id(x) ][0]

   for stats in HERO_STAT:

       if ( type(stats) == int or type(stats) == float ):

           File.write(var_name(stats)+" = ")
           File.write(str(stats)+"\n")


       elif ( type(stats) == str ):
           File.write(var_name(stats)+" = ")
           File.write("\""+stats+"\""+"\n")

   File.close()
   chdir("../")

 hp = 100
 mp = 20
 armor = "Magic Armor"

 heroName = input("[def_args] File name: ")
 write_hero_varStat(heroName,"w",hp,mp,armor)
 fileName = heroName+".py"
```

Задача в том, чтобы после создания этого **py-файла** я, будучи в вдругом модуле, мог импортировать один из созданных (*import*). Как можно выбрать один из них, напечатав его название через *input*?

Comment: Нашёл. varModule = __import__("ImportedModule")

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вам может помочь модуль `importlib`:

```
import importlib

module_name = 'my_module'
my_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

В папке с модулем должен быть файл **__init__.py**

Comment: Пишет, что файла нет.

Answer (score 0):

не пойму, тебе просто подключить надо модуль самописный?

просто import модуль (если он в той же директории что и твой модуль в котором ты сейчас)

если, скажем ты в директории 1 (dir1), а надо из директории 2 (dir2) и dir2 в dir1, вызвать модуль spam.py, То будет import dir2.spam

или ты хочешь узнать введя его название есть он или нет, тогда через os листай файлы в директории?

начинал писать нечто подобное, потом перевёл это на sqlite3, если интересно, сохранилось не много из того, что писал: http://pastebin.com/eWYR9bY7

Comment: А как именно сделать __import dir2.spam__?

Comment: нужно чтобы в папке откуда импортируешь модуль был пустой 2подчеркиванияinit2подчёркивания.py
могу видюху запилить

Comment: а вообще можно как-то импортировать набранное мной имя модуля?

Comment: разве что import модуль.
ну или в такой конструкции:
if ...:
.... import x
else:
.... import y

тут подробнее что можно, что нет:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: я нашёл способ через __module = 'war.py'
exec(open(module).read())__, но мне просто надо забрать переменные оттуда, а не запускать его.